# How I fix blurred display after awakening from sleep?

Tags: 16.04, unity, nvidia, compiz, nvidia-geforce

**Every time Ubuntu suspends, I have a blurred display after awakening from sleep.**

**How can I fix it?**

Ubuntu Releases (*tried*):

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Ubuntu 16.10
- Ubuntu Mate 16.04.02 LTS

Graphics: GeForce 6150SE nForce 430/integrated/SSE2

[Unanswered bug #1660057 on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1660057)

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu and maybe this is related with window manager